# How to use Laravel docker container & MySQL DB with a Vue one?

Tags: laravel, docker, vue.js, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have an app which uses **Vue CLI as a front-end** and **Laravel as a back-end**. Now I am trying to launch my app on a server using docker.

My docker skills can only allow me one thing: Vue docker container. But as far as I have to use Laravel as a back-end I have to create a container for that too (+ MySQL, of course).

So here what I've got: **Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN  npm install
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build: .
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
        ports: 
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
            - "/app/node_modules" 
            - ".:/app"
```

The problem is that I understand how to connect Laravel into **Dockerfile**. It just doesn't add up in my mind.

May be I should use **Ubuntu**, not just **node**? Anyways, I'm asking once again for your support

Comment: you need to add 2 new services: `laravel` and `mysql`

Comment: @Stefano, I guess you are right, but I don't know how to do it :(

Comment: the current one can work without problems. The only issue I see can come up in defining the url used by the frontend when communicating with the backend. I suggest to read about proxy reverse and nginx

Comment: you are already on a good path. add stuff to your docker-compose.yml, if you have a folder containing a laravel, generate a Dockerfile for that (if you need to adapt the original image to your needs) and so on

Comment: No progress bro.. @Stefano

Comment: Would this help you? https://medium.com/@crocodile2u/docker-setup-for-a-laravel-vue-project-90e4fd3acc7a

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this article](https://medium.com/@crocodile2u/docker-setup-for-a-laravel-vue-project-90e4fd3acc7a) you will need to follow the steps below.

1. Make your project folder look like this: (`d:` directory, `f:` file)

```js
d: backend
d: frontend
d: etc
    d: nginx
        d: conf.d
            f: default.conf.nginx
    d: php
        f: .gitignore
    d: dockerize
        d: backend
            f: Dockerfile
f: docker-compose.yml
```

2. Add **docker-compose.yml**

```js
    version: '3'
    services:
    www:
        image: nginx:alpine
        volumes:
            - ./etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        ports:
            - 81:80
        depends_on:
            - backend
            - frontend

    frontend:
        image: node:current-alpine
        user: ${UID}:${UID}
        working_dir: /home/node/app
        volumes:
            - ./frontend:/home/node/app
        environment:
            NODE_ENV: development
        command: "npm run serve"

    backend:
        build:
            context: dockerize/backend
        # this way container interacts with host on behalf of current user.
        # !!! NOTE: $UID is a _shell_ variable, not an environment variable!
        # To make it available as a shell var, make sure you have this in your ~/.bashrc (./.zshrc etc):
        # export UID="$UID"
        user: ${UID}:${UID}

        volumes:
            - ./backend:/app
            # custom adjustments to php.ini
            # i. e. "xdebug.remote_host" to debug the dockerized app
            - ./etc/php:/usr/local/etc/php/local.conf.d/
        environment:
            # add our custom config files for the php to scan
            PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR: "/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/:/usr/local/etc/php/local.conf.d/"
        command: "php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080"

    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7.22
        container_name: mysql
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "4306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./etc/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: tor
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
            SERVICE_NAME: mysql
```

3. Add **default.conf.nginx**

```js
    server {
        listen 81;
        server_name frontend;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://frontend:8080;
        }

        location /sockjs-node {
            proxy_pass http://frontend:8080;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            # below lines make ws://localhost/sockjs-node/... URLs work, enabling hot-reload
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        }

        location /api/ {
            # on the backend side, the request URI will _NOT_ contain the /api prefix,
            # which is what we want for a pure-api project
            proxy_pass http://backend:8080/;
            proxy_set_header Host localhost;
        }
    }
```

4. Add **Dockerfile**

```js
FROM php:fpm-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache $PHPIZE_DEPS oniguruma-dev libzip-dev curl-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip curl \
    && pecl install xdebug redis \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug redis
RUN mkdir /app
VOLUME /app
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8080
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080
```

5. DON'T FORGET TO ADD **vue.config.js** to your **frontend** folder

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    // options...
    devServer: {
        disableHostCheck: true,
        host: 'localhost',
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
        },
        watchOptions: {
            poll: true
        },
        proxy: 'http://localhost/api',
    } 
}
```

6. Run `sudo docker-compose up`
7. If you want to do migrations run this: `sudo docker-compose exec backend php artisan migrate`

Comment: I think the context for backend in docker-compose.yml should be `context: etc/dockerize/backend` instead of `context: dockerize/backend`.
Otherwise you get `build path /var/www/xxx/dockerize/backend either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL`

Comment: for those who getting NS server error; you need to set backend api url to 
http://localhost:81/api on frontend side , probably in your .env file. mine was http://localhost/api so it was throwing ns error.

Answer (score 5):

You will need 4 containers, defined in a `docker-compose` file:

- frontend (your Vue application, which you already have)
- backend (Laravel application)
- web server (eg. Nginx or Apache)
- database (MySQL)

It is possible to combine the 'web-server' and 'backend' containers into one, but this is generally bad advice.
Your compose file would look similar to this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app

  backend:
    build: ./backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/var/www/my_app
    environment:
      DB_HOST=db
      DB_PORT=3306

  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/var/www/my_app

  database:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dbpass
    volumes:
      - ./sql:/var/lib/mysql
```

where `./backend` contains the Laravel application code, `./frontend` contains the Vue application, and both contain a `Dockerfile`. Refer to [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) for specific instructions on each image needed. This exposes 3 ports to your host system: `8080` (Vue app), `8000` (Laravel app), and `3306` (MySQL).

Alternatively, you can omit the web server if you use the artisan cli's `serve` command in your Laravel container, similar to what you're already doing in the `Dockerfile` for your Vue application.

The image would have to include something like `CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'mma give u the bounty, but I have a question.. How about laravel migrations? How do I run it?

Comment: @TyomaInagamov The best way to do this is to have your Laravel container image do this on startup; make your image's entrypoint run a bash script, instead of `artisan serve` directly, and make that script run the migration prior to serving. This way, the latest schema will be migrated every time the container is started (eg. when you deploy a new version of the application).